# Regular expression - avoid the repetition of the sequence of the same letters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a check on the password inserted by a user, working on a PHP website.
My check wants to:

- at least 8 characters
- maximum 20 characters
- accept letters, numbers, and common special characters like (dot) @ + $ - _ !

Until this point I've been able to figure out the right expression, but now I want to add an other rule, where an user **can't write the same sequence of letter more then 1 time.**

Let's say that, not considering the repetition of two times of the same letter, if the user write the same string (equal or more than 3 characters) more then once, it should **not** match.

For example:

- abcde **not valid** - should be at least 8 characters
- abcde1234 **valid**
- abcd1abcd1 **not valid due to repetition of the string abcd1**

More examples (updated):

- abababab **not valid** - the string "ab" is repited 2 times or more
- aaaaaaaa **not valid** - the string aaa is repited more then once
- helloworld **valid** - even if there is the letter "l" repeated two times

Any suggestion?
I don't know is it's possibile to write down a correct RegExp, maybe I'm trying to do something impossibile.
Before leaving the idea, I was curious to check the opinion of someone who know more then me in RegExp.
Thanks in advance

Comment: how many characters should not he part of sequence?

Comment: What have you got so far? Also how deep does this "no repetitions" rule go? (Eg. would `abcde1fbcde2` – repeating `bcde` be allowed?)

Comment: what about `abababab` or `aaaaaaaa`

Answer (score 3):

```
^(?!.*?(.+)\1)([\w@+$!.-]+){8,20}$
```

seems to work well: http://regex101.com/r/cU9lD0/1

The tricky part is `^(?!.*?(.+)\1)` which reads "start of input, when not followed by: something, then some substring, then that substring once again".

That being said, all "password validation" is a quite pointless enterprise, which actually stops people from using [really good passwords](http://xkcd.com/936/).